# MySQL: select from table excluding where parameter

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select from table, excluding where id is something, say 7.

I have tried:
SELECT * FROM table where not exists(select * from table where user_id = '7');

Could anyone direct my to a place where I could get info on this?

Comment: your question is not clear plz put a query

Comment: Select name, property from table where id != / <> 7 ?

Comment: Isn't that as simple as this: `select * from tbl where id <> 7` ?

Comment: There is nothing so wrong with the question to deserve a down-vote. We should read questions carefully before down-voting people.

Comment: The question originally didn't show any evidence of code attempts or examples, but has since been edited. The downvoter should probably reconsider due to the revision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE id NOT IN(7);
```

You can find more comparison operators via the [Mysql Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html) on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

You can invert equality in your WHERE condition, like this:

```
SELECT field FROM table WHERE id != 7;
```